# Creating info files with same names of folders in different location

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Morning, I've got this section of powershell code which scans a selection of zip files in $path, and creates individual info files in $dest with the name of the info file being the same as the zip files in $path.

```
$path = 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\Powershell\Zip'
$dest = 'C:\Users\X\Dekstop\info\'

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -exclude '*.info' | ForEach { [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($dest+ $_.Name + ".info", $_FullName)}
```

The problem I have is although the code creates the info files nicely with the appropriate titles, it also copies the name of the original zip files and pastes it into the info file. Ideally I would like this zip file to be empty.

Any help with this atall? I've tried changing a few things around and cant get it to work how it should.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. However, the method WriteAllText takes two arguments (or three, but only two in your case). The first argument is for the path and the second is the contents of the file. You can read up on it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Why not try something like this instead (assuming I understand what you're trying to do). I added -Include "*.zip" or it would process all files except .info ones.

```
$path = 'C:\Users\X\Desktop\Powershell\Zip'
$dest = 'C:\Users\X\Dekstop\info\'

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -exclude '*.info' -Include '*.zip' |
    ForEach { New-Item -Path "$dest\$($_.Name + ".info")" -ItemType File }
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor description. The info files that are created are named after the zip files, which is what I want. But the name of the zip file also occurs within the info file, which is what im trying to get rid of. So i'm left with info files, named after the zip files, with nothing within them.

Comment: I did try it and the same occurred.

Comment: The code I pasted checks for zip-files in $path and foreach found zip-file it creates an empty file with the original name + .info

For instance; 
C:\Users\X\Desktop\Powershell\Zip\One.zip
C:\Users\X\Desktop\Powershell\Zip\Two.zip

Creates the following empty files
C:\Users\X\Desktop\info\One.zip.info
C:\Users\X\Desktop\info\Two.zip.info

Comment: I tried your code on its own rather than within my main script i've got and it worked, must be something else in there re-adding the name of the zip file.

Comment: Cheers for your help!